# Merriweather font not found on Windows

Tags: miktex, windows

I have a Latex document I want to compile. While under MacOSX with TexLive this is no problem at all, MikTex on Windows makes huge problems.

The tex starts as this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{style}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[light]{merriweather}
```

When compiling, I get the following error on Windows:

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The Merriweather-LightIt-osf-t1--base source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit

the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

In the Miktex pakcage manager, the merriweather package is shown as "installed". I use Miktex 2.9.6200 x64 with TexStudio 2.12.4

Said logfile shows:

```
2017-01-22 12:14:26,711+0100 INFO  makex - Trying to make PK font Merriweather-LightIt-osf-t1--base at 600 DPI...
2017-01-22 12:14:26,726+0100 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2017-01-22 12:14:26,853+0100 INFO  makex - Running ttf2pk.exe...
2017-01-22 12:14:34,443+0100 FATAL miktex-makepk - PK font Merriweather-LightIt-osf-t1--base could not be created.
```

After running updmap (as admin), the problem persists. The log now says:

```
2017-05-07 14:08:28,242+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makemf.exe" --verbose Merriweather-LightIt-osf-t1--base
2017-05-07 14:08:28,247+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The Merriweather-LightIt-osf-t1--base source file could not be found.
```

Someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the font installed or just the package?

Comment: just the package so far...

Comment: it's installed now. problem persists...

Comment: If you're fixed to that font you could use it with XeLaTex or LuaLaTeX. Do you have to use `pdflatex`?

Comment: @TeXnician sorry this would be cheating. The font package works fine with texlive but not with miktex. So there is a problem and it should be corrected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah, okay, I just thought of the fastest way for the OP...

Comment: The miktex package is faulty (probably outdated). I made a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2599/. As a workaround you can try to retrieve an update merriweather.map, move it is you document folder and add  `\pdfmapfile{=merriweather.map}` to your document. But is possible that more files are wrong in the package and that you get funny symbols or other error.

Comment: @TeXnician: Changing an existing document to xelatex/lualatex is not easy and not fast and as you don't have miktex you even can't know if it would work then with miktex.

Comment: It works fine for me on MiKTeX. Simply, as often, you have to run `updmap` from the command line (as administrator, I think), in order to refresh the type 1 fonts database(s).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Unfortunately, I am bound to pdflatex.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, the problem persists. Just the log output now looks different (see  edited post)

Comment: As I told you: the package is faulty.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: But  how comes *I* can compile?

Comment: No idea. Perhaps you updated something locally.

Comment: @Xenonite: Check if `Merriweather.map` is mentioned in the  `MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg` file. You also can check if `Merriweather` is ever mentioned in `psfonts.map` (it should appear 192 times).

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, it appears like "Map merriweather.map" in updmap.cfg. I can't anyhow locate a file psfonts.map anywhere.

Comment: There are two: one in `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config` (for every user) and one per user, in `C:\Users\Bernard\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config`. There are similarly `pdftex.map` and `dvipdfm.map` in analogous directories. These files should never be modified by hand, but only with `updmap`. You can add the switch `--verbose` if you want to see what happens.

Comment: @Bernard: believe me the problem is not a *missing* merriweather.map but a faulty map. The current version in miktex contains only a few entries for ly1. One doesn't need to hunt down updmap.cfg or maps files to check this. A simple `\pdfmapfile{=merriweather.map}` in the document is enough to test this.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I've just checked and you're perfectly right (I didn't doubt this, but I like to understand what happens). Finally, I do have another `Merriweather.map` file in my local tex directory,  which explains why it works on my system. The O.P. should just download it from CTAN and install it in his local texmf directory.